# Initial Error State In Logisim, Alternate Solution?

Tags: error, logisim

I am currently working on this problem for a computer systems class and have nearly (touch wood) found a solution. The solution I have right now correctly does what the brief asked for BUT starts with an error state. I need to work out some way to solve this problem so It still works the same way but initially there is no error state.

A Short Brief:
This circuit is designed to check if a Lock value matches a Key value, and turn an LED on if they match. Also the user is allowed a certain number of incorrect attempts - if the number of attemps becomes greater than the number of incorrect attempts allowed then the LED will not be able to be turned on even if the code is entered correctly.

Again my circuit does what I just described but starts with the error state in my latch on the right. Need a solution that flushes out this error state.

Thankyou,
Dylan[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this involves using an additional counter as an "enable line". Connecting the button to the clock of a one bit counter with the "Stay At Value" Acton on Overflow and using an AND gate to connect the output of the counter with the output of the Y gate so that until the button is pressed for the first time the reset part of the SR latch will be fed a low value to avoid initialisation errors, but once the button has been pressed the circuit still operates exactly the same.